# is there any difference between passing a CString and passing CString.GetBuffer to a %s in a CString.Format

Tags: c++, cstring

Given

```
CString buffer = "";
Cstring value = "blah";

buffer.Format ("%s %s", value, value.GetBuffer());
```

are the two ways of passing a `CString` equivalent, or does passing the `CString` have something happening behind the scenes that causes it to be equivalent?

Comment: Right from the `Format` docs: *The call will fail if the string object itself is offered as a parameter to Format.*

Comment: You only ever want to call `GetBuffer` if you must sidestep `CString`'s buffer management and write to its internal buffer. For every call to `GetBuffer` you need to call `ReleaseBuffer` so that the `CString` object can regenerate its internal state.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is correct. The first one seems to work, by coincidence while the latter uses a tool that serves a different purpose. The only correct way is to invoke the cast operator:

```
buffer.Format("%s", static_cast<LPCTSTR>(value));
```

Passing a `CString` object directly works by **coincidence** only since the pointer-sized value at the beginning of the object is interpreted as a pointer to a character array. The first class member of the `CString` class happens to be the `m_pszData` member - a pointer that stores the controlled sequence of characters.

[`GetBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880.aspx) should only be used if you have to manipulate a `CString`s contents directly. Note that this returns a non-`const` pointer. This is often used when interfacing with C APIs (see [Modifying CString Contents Directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awkwbzyc.aspx#_core_modifying_cstring_contents_directly) for details).